# Can I Change the PC File Location for Kindle For PC?

Tags: kindle

When I install Kindle for PC, a content folder (My Kindle Content) is created in the My Documents folder.  At work, My Documents maps to a home drive and I can only keep quite a small quantity of data on there.  I would like to change the My Kindle Content location to be on my local hard drive.  I can't find a way to do this through the UI, does anyone know of another way of doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should be pretty easy... But not straight away.

I just downloaded and installed Kindle for PC and under `Tools` > `Options`, there is a setting called content which allows you to change the folder.

When I went in to it, the button was disabled and it did not allow the folder to be changed.

All I did was log in to the kindle website and try to push a book from my archive (a dictionary that was delivered on the Ipad), it said delivered, I then went to the application and clicked the refresh button.

For some reason, it did not send the dictionary and I do not have it in the Kindle, but shortly after this, I went back in to options and the button was enabled.

I do not have a clue what step enabled it or why it was disabled in the first place, but I hope this helps you]
[image]

Comment: Right, this is exactly why I made the bounty. It was disabled on my install too, and now it magically enabled itself. I'll give you the bounty if you could figure out what the weirdness was about.

Comment: @EpsilonVector - All I can suggest/think is that it can't change until it is registered, signed in and synced for the first time. If you haven't done all the steps, it will not allow you to change.

Comment: ...you know what, I should know better than ask you to debug something you can't test or reproduce. I can't award it yet though (23 hours wait).

Answer (score 8):

Whether or not it's enabled requires selecting content. That is, you have to be in Library view, select All Items on the left, *then* open Tools -> Options -> Content and voila! Button enabled. This is **terrible** interface design, but at least we've figured it out.

(Incidentally, if you later open up a book for reading, and go to Options, it's disabled again. At least they're consistent...?)

Source: http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=200395770

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. Horrid design as you pointed out.

Comment: Wow. Design!!

Just to add extra 'wtf' to the interface it then creates a "My Kindle Content" directory in your directory rather than just taking it as-is. And saves the settings and greys-out the 'cancel' button once yo select it.

Answer (score 2):

Use `regedit.exe` to go into the registry and access the following key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Amazon.com\Kindle for PC
```

You can change the location by editing the `CONTENT_PATH` value.

I needed to change it since I hate having anything other than my OS on my SSD. The last thing I need is Kindle lowering the life expectancy of my SSD (it's also only 30GB!) and I was quite annoyed that it didn't give me the option to install everything onto my 1TB SATA drive.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem - I was unable to change the Contents folder.

The solution is that you have to close out all your books before you can change this folder (**File > Close Book**.) It would be nice if Amazon had included this simple instruction in the dialog box!

Comment: This is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had downloaded about 6 books when I decided to change the location. The button was disabled. I removed the 6 books from the device (my laptop), then the button was enabled and I could select my second hard drive which has more room. That was an easy fix.